# I believe I may have wrecked my pmadb functionality, and now PhpMyAdmin cannot seem to access any DBs

Tags: phpmyadmin

In a newly created database named "robust", I received a notice regarding PMA not being enabled, so I followed the info link (icon), and may have misinterpreted what was read. Thinking that it could be enabled globally, instead of unwanted cluttering of my "robust" database, I created a separate database called "pmadb". Then went to the window that had the link to run a program to create pma tables and clicked the link. It placed it in the "robust" I had created, so I copied the tables to the "pmadb" database, and then tried to drop those that were created in the wrong database. Now I cannot access any database, and most attempts to do anything result in an error popup saying "table 'robust.pma_tracking' does not exist". It will not even allow me to copy the tables back into the database that I do not want them in.

Comment: Please note your OS and version, Database engine[MariaDB/Mysql] and its version, even how you installed the DB engine and activate it. For example provide a link to where you followed an instruction for installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've found a sort of gap in between the automatically configured and manually configured pmadb ([phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage)).

The zero configuration option will try to create a 'phpmyadmin' database, but if it has trouble it will fall back on creating the tables in the current database. The problem is that once you removed the tables, phpMyAdmin was already looking there and tends to get confused. You should be able to drop the phpmyadmin database, all the tables that were mistakenly created in your other database, then log completely out and have everything work properly again when you log back in. I just tested a few scenarios and that worked to get me going again. If that isn't working the next thing to try would be logging in from the command line to drop the phpmyadmin database and extra phpmyadmin tables.

You might also have luck with setting `$cfg['ZeroConf'] = false;` in your configuration file `config.inc.php`.

Once you get logged in again, you can use the link on the bottom of the main page to create the tables globally in the phpmyadmin database, or you can [manually do it](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) (which is what I usually do).